# How do I create levels of indentation in my UITableView - similar to a comment reply - system where you can see the background of the table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I want to create a `UITableView` that visually resembles a commenting system for a blog where users can reply to a user, who can then be replied to by another user, etc. Kind of like a tree format.

[image]

I'm curious how I'd best implement this with a `UITableView`. I know there's a `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath` method on `UITableViewDelegate` and the cells have a similar property, but they seem to just translate the content of the `UITableViewCell` rather than the full cell itself and thus not exposing the background of the table view.

How would this be accomplished in a functional, MVC way? A property on the cell that translates itself?

Comment: You could make your cell background clear, but add an opaque view that initial takes up the whole width of the cell, but that you can adjust (with constraints) based on whatever logic you need. Your cells would still be full width, but they would appear not to be.

Comment: @rdelmar Where would it be best to handle the adjustment of this constraint? At creation in the data source?

Comment: Probably, but it's hard to tell without knowing how you're populating your cells. Where do you have the logic that determines where in the "tree" the text should go for a particular cell?

Comment: Define a standard cell which has a transparent background and contains only a UIView.  The UIView by default occupies the entire cell, but, based on desired indentation, the `origin.x` value is adjusted (with accompanying reduction in `width`) to provide the desired indentation.  The rest of the cell content is entirely within this adjustable UIView.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a basic CGAffineTransform be enough. Then you can also retrieve it and change it for cell indent animation or recycling purposes.

CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty)

Comment: I think that's overkill.